# Query with $In operator and limit on amount of data loaded

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, nosql

I’m running the following query

```
const query = { 
 $and: [
   { 
     $or: [ 
       {
         status: ‘PROCESSED’
       }, 

       {
         status: ‘IN_PROGRESS’
       }, 
     ],
   },  
   {
      content_id: { $in: contentIds }, 
   }, 
], 
};
```

in order to obtain all the data where the `content_id` is in a given list. I would like to obtain the 5 most recent data items for each `content_id`.

I know I can accomplish this by running an individual query for each content id, sorting by `content_date` `DESC` and setting a limit of 5 - I would like to achieve all of this in one query, rather than running individual ones for each content id, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.coll.aggregate([
     //match query
     {$group:{_id:"$content_id",items:{$push:"$$ROOT"}}}, 
     {$addFields:{items:{$slice:["$items", 5]}}}])
])
```

1. `$match` to check the content id is in the given list
2. Then `$group` on each content id, add entire document to `items` list
3. Then `slice` the array with the required elements

I suggest you to add a `sort` stage before `project` to ensure consistency across multiple hits.

Comment: Just to clarify - I’ll have the query in my question written as `{$match:{$and:..}}` followed by `{$sort: {‘created_date’: -1}}`, followed by the group and project queries above?

Comment: Yes. That would be perfect. Group then sort.

Comment: I’m getting an empty result set every time, not sure why. I copied the group and project queries exactly as in your example, do I need to replace anything with variables?

Comment: @Alk it should work. Show your pipeline(with match stage) and an example document that you expect to be in the result

Comment: @Alk this will help you the answer is almost there [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hC5YiZG_-fX)

Comment: Thanks vishal and Alex for clarifying things on time.

Comment: @turivishal this works after I replace project with addFields - I accepted, but perhaps its good to update the answer with that change

Comment: Thanks for editing that. Probably you needed one extra field than project.